# Error mapping class In an Azure App Service using automapper

Tags: automapper, azure-web-app-service

I'm working to an app service using AutoMapper to mapper entity to Data transfer object and I have this error.

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'cannot find the method 'AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.IProjectionExpression AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.Project(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>)'.'
```

I don't understand: I have other enitites mappe and they work.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I discovered that the problem is the AutoMapper version: the standard template ships with the 3.3.1 version, and if you update to a later version in this case gives and error.